# Jquery Ajax IE Response Slow

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, crash, response

Another IE problem - this time with ajax response data being too large.

With FF and Chrome the result is shown almost instantly. IE however freezes for a while before the results are shown. The format is HTML returned from a simple db query, and in some instances the response data is 900 rows long.

Seriously, what can I do to speed up IE?

Comment: use FF or Chrome ;D This issue sucks - we have the same problem with IE - are you targeting 9? or earlier? I'm targeting 8 and chalk it up to sheer speed of js processing (or the lack thereof).

Comment: Why is your AJAX returning 900 rows of data? this seems un-optimal for a quick request.  Can you post 5-10 sample rows of the data to give us an idea what you are dealing with?  I'm going to presume that JSON or CDF formatted data is the best solution otherwise.

Comment: Dealing with a table that contains 900 rows is not going to work very well in older versions IE even without javascript. I usually avoid it using server-side pagination with ajax.

Comment: This is an application. It uses a series of checkboxes to assemble queries on a member database of around 3000. It works fine on all queries/checkboxes except the ones which say eg. 'View All'

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

I was using tableSorter.js on the results. This injects alot of code into the DOM which IE doesn't like. I have disabled sorting for IE, and it now works much quicker.

Still very frustrating though - Every other browser works flawlessly, IE holding the world back as usual.